# What does this word mean?

Tags: word-meaning

My grandma used to say a word in Italian (it's the only language she spoke) that sounded something like this: "assodida". I spell it as it sounds. It seemed like some sort of a swear word, because she usually would yell it when something happened. Any idea what it is? The meaning is driving us crazy! Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like a dialectal term, where was your grandma from?

Comment: Can you say where the stress fell on the word? Was it more like *assòdida* or *assodìda*?

Comment: The stress seemed to fall in the middle, kind of like : assODida. My sister remembers it as sounding like this : ass SAW did da. Hope this helps. we are putting together a family story, and we are including all the expressions that were said over the years

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me guess... the word is *assordita*, meaning deafened, in the feminine form.

The implication is that a particular situation was extremely loud, like children crying, dishes breaking, etc., as to make your grandma deaf.

Comment: Yes, it could be, She always seemed mad when she said it, As if something happened when she said it.

Comment: Unfortunately *assordita* is not a very common word at all (I originally thought it did not even exist, before cheching in a dictionary). The most common form is *assordata*.

Answer (score 8):

Could it be *a' soreta / assorreta*? It is a rude answer to insults, not in Italian, but in Neapolitan dialect. It means *to your sister*, literally.

Unfortunately the only references I can find come from Yahoo Answers (not the most reputable of sites, I know...): [1](https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091216132225AAzoCfc) [2](https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090502042213AAh8ZST).

Comment: That could be it, It seems like the closest to the word. She always seemed mad when she said it. So maybe?

Comment: @Phil: I feel this to be far, far more likely. I never heard *assordita* used as an expletive, and the stress is consistent with *a soreta*, not with *assordita*.

Comment: Thank you. Like I said, we are appreciative of all the information.